# HTTP 3 support on Windows Server 2019 to improve performace of websites

Tags: http

Does Windows Server 2019 (Standard) support HTTP3 or can it be configured to SUPPORT HTTP3 for a .net and MVC based website?

From internet research, it seems that Windows Server 2022 supports HTTP3 but I could find any example where they talk of HTTP3 on older Windows server.

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Pro Webmasters. You may be able to get help on [sf]. I recommend reading their [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Comment: @JohnConde, Yes, could be but performance of website is collective responsibility of webmaster?

Comment: There's a lot that fits under that broad definition. If there is a Stack Exchange site that better suits a question it should be directed thee. Then the other stuff that doesn't have a good home can be asked here.